# Error: Can't convert text to date (Google Data Studio)

Tags: looker-studio

I have two different date column as `Order Date` and `_paid_date` and I am trying to use `_paid_date` as **Date Range Dimension** to find out total order paid, total revenue etc. but Data Studio takes it as text and when I tried to convert it to date, I get error like below.

However, when I use `Order Date` as Date Range Dimension, I get no error and it works.

I created another field with the formula it suggested in the error window and few other formulas that I found online but when I apply, it gets "no data" message in the scoreboard or any other chart that I am using.

How can I fix it so it is working in Date Range Dimension?

My date columns;

[image]

The error that I am receiving:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The supported format of datetime is `YYYY-[M]M-[D]D [[H]H:[M]M:[S]S]`.

That's why `Order Date` work and `_paid_date` doesn't.

Reference:

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6401549?hl=en#use-dates-and-times-in-calculated-fields&zippy=%2Cin-this-article